# Entity Framework 5 poor performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have 5 entities:

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AlbumArtist> AlbumArtists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Song> Songs { get; set; }

}

public class AlbumArtist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AlbumArtist> AlbumArtists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AlbumArtist> AlbumArtists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

public class Song
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AlbumArtist> AlbumArtists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, there are a lot of many-to-many relationships. I populate my entities and then try to save them to DbContext in that way:

```
_albumArtists.ForEach(delegate(AlbumArtist albumArtist)
{
    if (albumArtist.Id == 0)
    {
            _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
            _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
});
...
```

or in that way:

```
_albumArtists.ForEach(delegate(AlbumArtist albumArtist)
{
    if (albumArtist.Id == 0)
    {
            _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else
    {
            _dbContext.AlbumArtists.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
});
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
...
```

It takes forever to save my entities to DbContext. I even tried to do the following:

```
Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

But it didn't helped. By the way, there are for about 17 000 Songs and 1 700 Albums.

What is wrong???

Please help!

**PS**

Here is my full code: https://github.com/vjacheslavravdin/PsyTrance/blob/master/PsyTrance/Program.cs
Maybe you can suggest how to simplify it.

Thanks!

Comment: Savings 17 000 songs and 1 700 albums will take a while. If you're only modifying a portion of those, it should not take so long. I can't tell from your code whether `_albumArtists` contains all, or just the modified/added ones.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just let the automatic change detection tell whether you've changed things? It'd be much simpler, and ensure that you're not resaving things that don't need to be.

Comment: _albumArtists contains all... It takes for about 4 hours!

Comment: How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I published my full code in the bottom of my question. Please look through it.

Comment: Entity Framework (and ORMs in general) are not intended to be used for massive batch operations. Create a pure SQL script to insert your data and then perform daily 1 record operations with an ORM.

Comment: Thanks, but it's too complicated task to script the whole graph with T-SQL.

Comment: This could be a problem with your database, an unfortunate trigger for example. You say that inserting 15000 items takes 4 hours. How much time 15000 inserts need WITHOUT the entitry framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly a couple of clarifications:

EF is not significantly slower than other methods for batch based operations. in my tests you can get perhaps a 50% improvement with a raw SQL Command and maybe up to 10 times faster with SQL Bulk copy but EF is not much slower than comparative methods as a general rule (though often perceived as very slow). For most applications EF will give suitable performance numbers even in batch scenarios given the correct tuning. (see my article here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/3/24/entity_framework_comparative_performance and http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/8/17/mssql_and_large_insert_statements)

Because of the way EF does change tracking its has potential to far exceed the performance of how most people would write SqlCommand based insert statements (theres a whole lot of caviats to do with query planning, round trips and transactions that make it pretty hard to write optimally performing bulk insert statements). I have proposed these additions to EF here (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/377636) but havent implemented them yet.

You are exactly right with your decision to turn off auto detect changes, each .Add or .Attach action with detect changes on enumerates the tracking graph, therefore if you're adding 17k additions on the same context you will need to enumerate the graph 17000 times over a total of 17000 + 16999 + ...+ 2 + 1 = 144,500,000 entities, no wonder its taking so long right? (see my article here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/5/7/entityframework_performance_and_autodetectchanges)

Save changes always needs to enumerate the tracking graph (it calls detect changes internally)  so your first way is going to be slow as its actually going to be doing the same number of tracking calls as above.

The second way is much better but it still has a pretty major flaw which I imagine is twofold, firstly the graph is really big when you go to save changes (bigger graphs have exponentially higher tracking times), and secondly its going to take up a lot of memory to persist the whole graph at once especially given that EF stores two copies of each of your entities.

A better way is to persist your graph in chunks. some

```
//With Auto detect changes off.
foreach(var batch in batches)//keep batch size below 1000 items, play around with the numbers a little
{
    using(var ctx = new MyContext())//make sure you create a new context per batch.
    {
        foreach(var entity in batch){
             ctx.Entities.Add(entity);
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I would expect you should target around 17-30s to do all 17k rows.

by doing this with raw SQL commands you may be able to get this to around 12-20s;

with a reimplementation with bulk copy you could probably get this down to 2-5s

Comment: I can vouch for entity framework not being that terrible at performance, at least, being the root cause. Yes, it is slower, but it comes down to your own methods of handling your data. I was tasked to re-write one of our companies batch import processes (we're talking hundreds of thousands of records nightly), and at first did not realize the performance impact Entity Framework had, but after tons of tuning I was able to get it to run reasonably fast. It turned out my version was faster than the old version that used plain SQL because of the way I handle the data. There's always more to it

Comment: @DavidAnderson-DCOM As with every framework theres good and bad ways of doing things, a lot of people dont really understand whats going on under the covers with EF which can encourage them to use some bad ways of doing things but this doesnt mean the framework as a whole is slow :) I had a pretty similar story when I first did EF perf tuning to yours

Comment: "turn of" --> "turn off"?